# Reverse for 'editar_arvore' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['arvore/editar_arvore/(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: django, django-templates

I am having this error when I try to click to edit a form already submitted, it is as if I was not passing the arvore.id in the template ver_arvore. When I change arvore.id to a number(eg. 1) I can see all my records in the database, otherwise I have the NoReverse Match error. It is as if the view ver_arvore is not saving my dictionary, as shown in the traceback

My models:

```
class Arvore(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    nivel = models.CharField(
        default='Planta',
        max_length=50,
        choices=(
            ('Planta', 'Planta'),
            ('Sistema', 'Sistema'),
            ('Equipamento', 'Equipamento'),
            ('Peça', 'Peça'),
        )
    )
    criticidade = models.TextField()
    requisitos = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    descricao = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fabricante = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    pai = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    localizacao = models.CharField(max_length=250,blank=True, null=True)
    link_historico = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    link_pm = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    link_foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'arvore'

class FormArvore(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Arvore
```

my url:

```
app_name = 'arvore' 

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ver_arvore, name='ver_arvore'),
    path('cadastro_arvore/', views.cadastro_arvore, name='cadastro_arvore'),
    path('editar_arvore/<int:id>/', views.editar_arvore, name='editar_arvore'),
    path('deletar_arvore/<int:id>/', views.deletar_arvore, name='deletar_arvore'),
]
```

My views:

```
def cadastro_arvore(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = FormArvore
        return render(request, 'arvore/cadastro_arvore.html', {'form': form})

    form = FormArvore(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if not form.is_valid():
        form = FormArvore(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'arvore/cadastro_arvore.html', {'form': form})

    form.save()
    return redirect('arvore:cadastro_arvore')


def ver_arvore(request):
    arvore = Arvore.objects.all().order_by('id')
    paginator = Paginator(arvore, 9)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    arvore = paginator.get_page(page)

    pesquisa_id = request.GET.get('pesquisa_id')
    pesquisa_nome = request.GET.get('pesquisa_nome')
    pesquisa_tag = request.GET.get('pesquisa_tag')
    pesquisa_nivel = request.GET.get('pesquisa_nivel')

    if pesquisa_id:
        arvore = Arvore.objects.filter(id=pesquisa_id)

    if pesquisa_nome:
        arvore = Arvore.objects.filter(nome=pesquisa_nome)

    if pesquisa_tag:
        arvore = Arvore.objects.filter(tag=pesquisa_tag)

    if pesquisa_nivel:
        arvore = Arvore.objects.filter(nivel=pesquisa_nivel)

    return render(request, 'arvore/ver_arvore.html', {
        'arvore': arvore
    })



def editar_arvore(request, id):
    arvore = get_object_or_404(Arvore, pk=id)
    form = FormArvore(instance=arvore)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        return render(request, 'arvore/editar_arvore.html', {'form': form, 'arvore': arvore})
    form = FormArvore(request.POST, instance=arvore)

    if not form.is_valid():
        return render(request, 'arvore/editar_arvore.html', {'form': form, 'arvore': arvore})

    arvore.save()
    return redirect('arvore:ver_arvore')


def deletar_arvore(request, id):
    arvore = get_object_or_404(Arvore, pk= id)

    arvore.delete()

    return redirect('arvore:ver_arvore')
```

ver_arvore.html

```
  {% for equipamentos in arvore %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ equipamentos.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ equipamentos.tag }}</td>
        <td><a href="{%url 'arvore:editar_arvore' arvore.id %}"> {{ equipamentos.nome }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ equipamentos.nivel }}</td>
        <td>{{ equipamentos.fabricante}}</td>
        <td>{{ equipamentos.modelo }}</td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
```

editar_arvore.html

```
<form action="{% url 'arvore:editar_arvore' arvore.id  %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h2>Registro Árvore de Equipamentos</h2></legend>
        <table class="table">
            {{ form }}
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Adicionar</button>
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Cancelar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </fieldset>
</form>
<hr>
<form action="{% url 'arvore:deletar_arvore' arvore.id  %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <td>
        <tr>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Deletar">

        </tr>
    </td>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

traceback:
[Dic at ver_arvore isnt working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7T2C.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over arvore. Which means arvore is a dict. Therefore arvore.id wont work. For example try equipamentos.id as id for the url parameter

`<td><a href="{%url 'arvore:editar_arvore' equipamentos.id %}"> {{ equipamentos.nome }}</a></td>`

Comment: Thanks dude, I don't pay attention to this detail.